# Accessing Kubernetes Web UI (Dashboard)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, kubectl, kube-dns

I have installed a Kubernetes with Kubeadm tool, and then followed the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/) to install the Web UI (Dashboard). Kubernetes is installed and running in one node instance which is a taint master node.

However, I'm not able to access the Web UI at `https://<kubernetes-master>/ui`. Instead I can access it on `https://<kubernetes-master>:6443/ui`.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL you are using to access the dashboard is an endpoint on the API Server. By default, `kubeadm` deploys the API server on port `6443`, and not on `443`, which is what you would need to access the dashboard through `https` without specifying a port in the URL (i.e. `https://<kubernetes-master>/ui`)

There are various ways you can expose and access the dashboard. These are ordered by increasing complexity:

- If this is a dev/test cluster, you could try making `kubeadm` deploy the API server on port `443` by using the `--api-port` flag [exposed](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go#L83) by `kubeadm`.
- Expose the dashboard using a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/) of type `NodePort`.
- Deploy an [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) controller and define an ingress point for the dashboard.

Comment: Thank you. Can I just ask then, why does official Kubernetes documentation state that we can access the UI without the port? Is that a mistake or?

Comment: Given that there's a variety of ways to deploy Kubernetes, the ability to access the UI without specifying the port really depends on what you used to deploy the cluster (which in turn determines the port where the API server is listening).